# postgres query a string not starting with a given set of characters using LIKE or ILIKE keywords

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible in Postgresql to query a string that does not start with vowels (or a given set of characters) using only `LIKE` or `ILIKE` keyword?

For example I was playing with [this sample DB](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/dvdrental.zip) and was trying to extract from `Customer` the `first_name`s that do not start with vowels:

```
SELECT first_name
FROM Customer
WHERE first_name NOT ILIKE '[aeiou]%'
ORDER BY first_name;
```

This query however does not work and I get results like `Aaron`, `Adam` etc. The problem is in the square brackets because the condition `NOT ILIKE 'a%'` works.

I know there are previous answers to similar questions but 1) they are not in postgresql and 2) they use regular expressions or substringing whereas I'd like to know if a solution using `LIKE`/`ILIKE` exists

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, `LIKE/ILIKE` do not support regex syntax, which is what your're trying to use in the provided example. `LIKE/ILIKE` only supports `%` and `_` special symbols and those don't do what you need them to in a single expression.

You could probably get away with something like

```
SELECT first_name
FROM Customer
WHERE first_name NOT ILIKE 'a%'
  AND first_name NOT ILIKE 'e%'
  AND first_name NOT ILIKE 'i%'
  AND first_name NOT ILIKE 'o%'
  AND first_name NOT ILIKE 'u%'
ORDER BY first_name;
```

...but it'd take a very good reason to do it that way, rather than using regex.

Answer (score 2):

In addition you can use ^ symbol (beginning of word (string))

```
SELECT first_name
FROM Customer
WHERE not first_name ~* '^[aeiou]'
ORDER BY first_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` (and it's Postgres extension `ILIKE`) does not support regular expressions in SQL.

If you want to use a regex, use you can use the standard-compliant `similar to` or the Postgres specific `~*` operator

```
SELECT first_name
FROM Customer
WHERE not first_name ~* '^[aeiou]*'
ORDER BY first_name;
```

Comment: It would be either `SIMILAR TO `[AEIOU]%` or ` first_name ~* '^[aeiou]'` apparently

Comment: @FrancescoBoi: ah, right. Thanks